# Pandas Dataframe sort by a column

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, dataframe, multiple-columns

I have a Python Pandas Data Frame. The df has 2 columns, I would like to sort the df by the second column.

```
   Kappa_prod   Angle
0   0.004511    -5.457840
1   0.003977    -5.312861
2   0.004476    -5.311292
3   0.003644    -117.579594
4   0.003306    -117.542817
```

I would like to sort the df by Angle (ascending order).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use this:

```
df.sort_values("Angle", inplace=True)
```

By default `ascending=True` is passed to the above call. For more information check the documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html).