# Seaborn barplot with bars ordered by y axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, bar-chart, seaborn

I would like to order the bars in my `seaborn` plot using the y axis, so in this case the `'Fraud Probability'` in descending order. How can I do that?
This is my code:

```
plt.figure(figsize = (16,5))
ax = sns.barplot(x = 'Customer ID', y = "Fraud Probability", data = fraud_df)
for item in ax.get_xticklabels(): item.set_rotation(90)
plt.show()
```

And this is the resulting plot: [image]

Comment: Just sort your data frame using `Fraud Probability`, save it in a new dataframe and plot it. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46072509/pandas-dataframe-sort-by-a-column) is a link on how to sort the data frame. Use `ascending=False` to have the values sorted in descending order. Simple!

Answer (score 2):

The dataset was already sorted. Anyway after sorting the dataset, in this case the name is `fraud_df`, you just need to specify `order = fraud_df['Customer ID']` like this:

```
ax = sns.barplot(x = 'Customer ID', y = "Fraud Probability", data = fraud_df, order = fraud_df['Customer ID'])
```